# Train fire detection using opencv SVM

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I'm using SVM since I need ML to train my classifier, and I saw on several papers on fire detection that they used SVM and logistic regression but since there is no logistic regression in 2.4.9 I'm planning on using SVM. I'm using opencv 2.4.9 since people said opencv 3 is buggy.

Im new to this so it will be helpful if we start from basic

I have prepared several fire and non-fire videos ready to be extracted into frames. I'm new to opencv and everything about classifiers. My question is what are the basics in training a classifier specifically SVM, What format do I need my images to be and how do I train them? Are there any good links for a tutorial? I found one in opencv documentation but it doesn't teach on training using image. What do I need in determining parameters and what are the parameters for? Thanks in advance

Comment: You need first to extract features from your images in order to train an SVM.
Feature extraction algorithms depend a lot on the application.
If you are using OpenCV I would recommend taking a look at this tutorials about keypoint detectors and feature extraction.  http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d27/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Do I need my images to be in a specific format? or jpg is doable?

Comment: And where do I put the extracted features? I can't figure out in the svm train method which parameter is that

Comment: Take a look at the opencv samples that come with the distribution. There are several examples that use SVMs.

Comment: The example about non linear svm doesn't show how to train using images and im having hard time translating it into image training

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a conceptual question that calls for lots of papers and tutorials to explain. However, As it was explained in the comments I try to elaborate on  feature extraction. Feature descriptors should be robust against scaling, translate and rotation. This robustness is literally referred to as invariant features. For instance, moments and its derivatives are one of the most famous type of invariant against rotation, scaling and translate. You may find the usage of Hu moments as explained in this [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwj7zdmW8fHKAhVB4XIKHZGsClsQFggnMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fro.ecu.edu.au%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D7351%26context%3Decuworks&usg=AFQjCNEgn52gLwdVmogc2lYt1o62_mElbA&sig2=N3RZaphxHyN77lYQM5qOsQ&bvm=bv.114195076,d.bGQ&cad=rja). 
Flame or fire detection is something different. The feature corresponds to flame can be extracted from fire's dynamic texture. For instance, fire has a special color texture that segregates it from the background. The conventional flame detectors make use of infrared sensors to detect a flame. In image processing, or RGB world, we can do the same by considering the nature of flame itself. Flame emits a significant portion of its energy through heat and infrared ray. So, one can expect a major portion of red channel to be devoted to flame. See the following image for example.[image]
[image]

In the processed image, the red channel is converted to BW image by imposing a threshold. To be more clear, I have separated the 3 channels as below.
R:[image: red channel] G:[image: green channel] B:[image: blue channel]
It is evident the Red channel has more to say about the flame. Therefore, it can be concluded that the flame is where R channel has a portion of its information, then G and finally B channel. See [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiSnvna8fHKAhUhyXIKHbFlC-UQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.253.818%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNEmgD3Ngo8uFTl02DjLm0Tl6nEDdg&sig2=knfjy-lupW_XuOu44S9R6g&bvm=bv.114195076,d.bGQ&cad=rja).
Your feature vector, then, will be a three dimensional vector about, for example, the contour of the flame in three RGB channels. SVM classifiers are now ready to be used. Sometimes, the video may contain flam-liked segments that should be avoided and they lead to false alarms otherwise. SVM, assists you to accept or reject a flame candidate. To train your support vector machine, collect some true flames and some images that may be misjudged by your feature extractor. Then, label them with positive and negative features. Finally, let opencv do the magic and train it. For more information about SVM, please watch this video by Patrick Winston, MIT on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PwhiWxHK8o).

**UPDATE ----**
As you are curious about creating feature vector, I brought to you the following example. Assume that R,G,B channels are finely segregated so as to one can call them statistically independent as the follow; This is not true in real images wherein R,G,B planes are not statistically independent.
[image]
Therefore, a point in the RGB image will have 3 representations in RGB channels. For instance, a flame will make 3 spots on all the R,G,B planes. The area of each spot, for example, is being traced here. Label the flame spot in RGB image as "A".
[image] 
The representations of the area A were depicted above in R , G , B images. A_r , A_g , A_b denote the corresponding area of the area A on R,G,B planes, respectively.

[image]
Therefore, point A will be represented by a triplet (Ar,Ag,Ab) in xyz plane. SVM, now accepts this vector as input and decide if it signifies a real flame.
The areas, normalized format, is one of the many geometrical features that you can involve in decision making process. Other useful features of this kind are aspect ratios, moments and so on.

In a nutshell, you have to do the following:
**1 - Find the flame-liked areas.

2 - Trace the candidate spot in all of the R,G,B planes.

3 - Extract the feature( I suggest moments) in every plane.

4 - Form the feature vector 

5 - Feed the SVM with this vector**

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I have a question.
What you mean is I will extract feature using a three dimensional vector?
I'm having hard time how to use that As I see in documentation here http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html  I input that in the keypoints parameter?

Comment: @RedViper, I updated my post.

Comment: what is the edge of moments against surf? as feature because I come across surf alot in the internet when it comes to feature extractions

Comment: so what I understand on your 5 steps is
1. make a .txt of images in this format img1.jpg  1  140 100 45 45
2.  loop through the images using #1 and store the rgb plane of each
3. extract the feature of each plane (still reading on how to do this)
4. form using #3 the feature vector to pass as parameter in training svm

Comment: About surf and sift features, they detect blob-like points in an image. They are favorable in stereo imaging and sometimes character recognition. I think geometric features outperform sift/surf features.

Comment: Let classify flame and non-flame features with 0, 1 labels. Then you will have a matrix which every row of it represents a feature vector and a label vector. Assume 6 images, 1.png, 2.png, ..., 6.png. First three images correspond to a flame while 4.png, 5.png, 6.png don't. Image 1.png yields f11, f12, ..... Features. Similarly, image 2.png leads to f21, f22, .....

Comment: Therefore, feature matrix will be: F=[f11, f12,...f1n; f21,f22,....,f2n;.....;fm1,fm2,....,,fmn] and label vector will be: L=[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

Comment: Is there a recommended ratio for positive and negative images in training? does it need to be 1:1?

Comment: I have not encountered to such limitation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :))

Comment: Hi sorry for the follow up question but if your still willing to help it is greatly appreciated. I have researched on extraction of hu moments in opencv and I even found this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBp3EZqIr3I everything I see is they make the picture black and white, but I thought it should be colored since to detect fire the rgb of the pixel is needed, does that mean moments isnt applicable?

Comment: There is no need for the image to be in bw, it can be gray scale, however, if you are to use rgb image, you should separate it to 3 red,green,blue planes.

Comment: Got stuck while coding, I got confused again at number 2. My understanding is that For example I have 1000 images, I get the rgb of all and the median?

Comment: Let me add this, working with bw or gray-scale images is dictated by your feature extraction method.

Comment: Or do you want me to post another question here in stackoverflow to indicate what I already did?

Comment: Let go through it step by step. Median, gaussian and other filtering methods alike correspond to pre-processing. As I mentioned before, take rgb planes and do as follow. Search for areas in three planes. Try to relate them in all of them, this is the most critical step. It means, you should track area "A" in all of the planes. Then you have point A and three areas refers to it. Now, take your desired moments extraction method. In case of hu moments you will come with seven of them. Pack all three set of moments in a vector, 3x7 moments in a vector which has 21 elements. Finally, feed SVM.

Comment: Go through with that, if you could not find a way, post a new one and alert me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes right so your job now is to make a .txt file with data on each image that you gonna process.
The ones which are true will be denoted by +1 followeed with feature set and end it with a -1
and the ones which are false images of fires will start with -1 followed with feature sets and end it with -1 again before starting with feature set of next image
its gonna b a tedious job but I am sure ul manage that 
and finally save that file with extension of .train and not .txt
so your training file name gonna be filename.train